# Difference in casting with volatile and without volatile

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two C definitions?

```
volatile uint32_t *ptr1 = (volatile uint32_t *)0x20040000;
volatile uint32_t *ptr1 = (uint32_t *)0x20040000;
```

Comment: The difference is how many characters you type in the process of writing the two statements.  The result is exactly the same: the address `0x20040000` is treated as a pointer to a `volatile` 32-bit unsigned int.

Comment: I thought volatile is just a hint.

Comment: No, `register` and `inline` are just hints. `volatile` is definitely not just a hint.

Comment: @EdHeal: not really — `volatile` means that the optimizer cannot optimize accesses made via the pointer.  For example, with a non-volatile variable, if you write `int i = (*ptr1 >> 3) | (*ptr1 << 3);` the compiler is not obliged to read `*ptr1` twice; it might save the value.  With the volatile qualifier, it is obliged to read `*ptr1` twice — it cannot optimize the second read away.  Of course, nothing controls whether the first read is shifted left or right; that's a separate issue.  But there will be two reads of (the volatile) `*ptr1`, accessing the memory twice.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - not a good way for implementing multi-thrreaded applications. Mutex is the order of the day

Comment: @EdHeal That is correct, `volatile` is not intended for multi-threading. It is intended for hardware control. If the address in the question points to a hardware register, the `volatile` keyword guarantees that the compiler will not optimize away or reorder reads/writes to the hardware.

Comment: @EdHeal: I never said anything about multi-threading.  I just explained the semantics of `volatile` are.  You're right though.  That's why C11 and C++11 have all the other facilities in `<threads.h>`:  _The types are
`cnd_t`
which is a complete object type that holds an identifier for a condition variable;
`thrd_t`
which is a complete object type that holds an identifier for a thread;
`tss_t`
which is a complete object type that holds an identifier for a thread-specific storage
pointer;
`mtx_t`
which is a complete object type that holds an identifier for a mutex; …_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - So for day-to-day programming it should not be a consideration along with the keyword `register`

Comment: @EdHeal: correct; `volatile` is seldom needed.  As user3386109 said, it is usually (correctly) used with things like memory-mapped device controls that can change value without the C compiler making the change.  It is far more often abused than used correctly.

Comment: @EdHeal @Jonathan In embeedded systems, without a SO, `volatile` is a key thing. Pointing to mcu/cpu registers and use them in `ISR routines`, without the `volatile` variables make the compiler optimizator able to compile wrong firmware/software.

Answer (score 1):

**Volatile** doesn't have any effect on the cast.

From [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_%28computer_programming%29):

In computer programming, particularly in the C, C++, C#, and Java programming languages, the volatile keyword indicates that a value may change between different accesses, even if it does not appear to be modified.

Comment: Can you explain it in detail please!

Comment: Esentially, if your example was asking the difference between having or not having volatile before the type at the start of the declaration it would make a difference. They keyword volatile simply tells the compiler that the value of this variable could change at any point, not just by it's own code writing to it. For example, an embedded application may have different CPU registers which could be changed by other components.